# How to kill an An Android Application Programatically

Tags: android

I am working on Android applications and getting one problem. I am using Exit Button, so when I am clicking the exit button (which is present in last activity of the application or in Middle but not in First Activity) then the application should close, and when I am restarting the application it should start from the first screen.

But my problem is it's not killing the application  and when I am starting again it is starting from the previously paused activities.

I have used `System.exit(0)` and also used `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid())`.

but those are not working.

Comment: Duplicate questions :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631289/how-to-destroy-my-application/7683039#7683039  

Please research your question before posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in an Activity: `this.finish()`

in a Service: `this.stopSelf()`

in a Receiver: `return;`

Answer (score 2):

1. You should not. It goes against basic android ideas. Please read about applciation lifecycle.
2. You could finish individual activity / service  with finish()

Answer (score 0):

`System.exit(0)` will do the job. However, it is not at all recommended. Android does some caching, and saving state, so as to relaunch your appp quicker, the next time you launch it.. so you do not want to be messing around with that.

This has been discussed many times, please research your question before posting.